# DATE_FORMAT in postgresql

Tags: mysql, database, postgresql, postgresql-9.1, postgresql-9.0

I'm working in postgresql and I need to convert the date format in query itself,
in mysql there is option called `DATE_FORMAT` and I can use a query like this:

```
Select DATE_FORMAT(date_time, '%b %e, %Y, %T') from table_name
```

is there any option in postgresql?
Please let me know if any?

Comment: What's so hard looking this up in the manual?

Answer (score 43, accepted):

If I modify your

```
Select DATE_FORMAT(date_time, '%b %e, %Y, %T') from table_name
```

to

```
Select DATE_FORMAT(now(), '%b %e, %Y, %T')
```

it will return `Aug 21, 2012, 16:51:30`.

You can do the same thing in Postgresql:

```
Select to_char(now(), 'Mon-dd-YYYY,HH24:mi:ss')
```

will return you `Aug-21-2012,16:52:08`

Hope your problem is sort out.

Answer (score 17):

Use to_char():

http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-formatting.html

I don't know what `'%b %e, %Y, %T'` produces as an output (and you didn't supply a sample output), so I cannot give you the equivalent format mask for Postgres.

The following produces an ANSI date:

```
select to_char(date_time, 'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss')
from table_name;
```

Answer (score 11):

Try this

```
SELECT to_char(date_time, 'dd.mm.YYYY') from table_name
```

Answer (score 5):

`to_char`, eg:

```
to_char(creation_date, 'FMDD.MM.YYYY, HH24:MI:SS') AS creation_date_f
```