# Convert unix timestamp to a date format, group by it and count

Tags: postgresql

I've found a post describing [how to count records grouped by date format](http://www.cowboycoded.com/2010/04/19/mysql-group-by-day-month-or-year-using-a-timestamp-column/). However, the author in this post uses MySQL:

```
select count(*), DATE_FORMAT(created_at,"%Y-%m-%d") as created_day FROM widgets GROUP BY created_day
```

Also, I store a unix timestamp under the `started_at` field, so first I would have to convert it to a date or timestamp format. How can I do all of this in PostgreSQL?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12052705/date-format-in-postgresql

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, I figured it out thanks to your comments! I just had  to do something like this with the timestamp:

```
to_char(to_timestamp(started_at), 'YYYY-Mon')
```

Answer (score 2):

Try something like:

```
select count(*), date_trunc(to_timestamp(created_at),'day') as created_day 
FROM widgets 
GROUP BY created_day;
```

`to_timestamp` converts unix timestamp to a proper `timestamp` and `date_trunc` truncates the timestamp to days.