# DATE_FORMAT in Postgresql?

Tags: postgresql

I have this query using MySQL I need to convert it to PostgreSQL query

```
SELECT
    count(*) AS aggregate
FROM
    "contracts"
WHERE
    DATE_FORMAT(created_at, '%Y-%c') = '2022-1'
```

I got this error:

```
Query 1 ERROR: ERROR:  function date_format(timestamp without time zone, unknown) does not exist
LINE 6:  DATE_FORMAT(created_at, '%Y-%c') = '2022-1'
```

Comment: Could it be a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12052705/date-format-in-postgresql ? If that's the case you'll find your answer there.

Comment: Also, I could very well be wrong but I believe there are better ways of filtering by month in both postgresql and mysql. You could look at https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/190774/search-for-current-month-data-in-postgresql-9-2 for inspiration

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `TO_CHAR` to format the date or timestamp.

```
SELECT count(*) AS aggregate
FROM contracts
WHERE TO_CHAR(created_at, 'yyyy-mm') = '2022-01'
```

Or use a sargable alternative

```
SELECT count(*) AS aggregate
FROM contracts
WHERE created_at >= '2022-01-01' 
  AND created_at <  '2022-02-01'
```